# How to call a function in scheme

Tags: scheme

I was trying to test a small portion of code and for some reason I have some errors. here is the code. here `tab` is just a function returning a list and `translate` is another function.

```
(define p
  (let ((x (car tab)) (y (cadr tab)))
    (list translate(x) y)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function call is written as `(f args)` where `f` is the name of the function and `args` a space-separated sequence of arguments.

So to call `tab` without arguments, you'd write `(tab)` and to call `translate` with the argument `x`, you'd write `(translate x)`.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a common procedure in Scheme and if you evaluate it will evaluate the symbol and you'll get a implementation dependent representation of the procedure object:

```scm
+ ; ==> <procedure: +> (or something similar)
```

Now `+` is just a variable that, when evaluated, evaluates to a procedure. How to call it is just to suround it with parentheses:

```scm
(+) ; ==> 0
```

What happens is that Scheme sees the parentheses, then evaluates the first argument `+` and it becomes the procedure `<procedure: +>`. Since it'a procedure the arguments are evaluated in any order and last the procedure is applied with those evaluated arguments.

If `tab` is a procedure object you cannot apply `car` or `cdr` to it. You can do it to the result of calling it if it evaluates to a pair. Likewise if you want to call a procedure `translate` with argument`x` it needs to look like `(translate x)`. Putting it all together:

```scm
(define p
  (let* ((tab-result (tab))
         (x (car tab-result)) 
         (y (cadr tab-result)))
    (list (translate x) y)))
```